# Display hidden object from another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having a little trouble here and hopefully someone can give me a hint on what I'm doing wrong. The object within the main div is hidden and I need it show when I click the button within the secondary div. I'm getting the secondary div to "close" after the button is clicked but I just can't seem to figure out how to make the "checked" object to show.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="separate">
  <div class="main">
    <h1>Mechanical Room</h1>
    <object class="checked"></object>
  </div>
  <div class="secondary">
    <div class="heading">
      <h2>Mechanical Room</h2>
      <button class="check-in">Check In</button>
      <object></object>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".check-in").click(function () {
    $(this).closest(".separate").children(".secondary").fadeOut(200);
    $(this).closest(".separate").children(".main").find("object").show();
});
});
```

Comment: That's what I thought but it doesn't seem to be. I must be missing something...

Comment: looks like `show()` is not working.... try `$(this).closest(".separate").find(".main object").css('display', 'block');`

Comment: demo: [with css-display](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/58Q8y/1/), [with show](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/58Q8y/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your div is set to hidden by visibility then show() method won't show [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8r3tG/)

You need to set `.css('visibility','visible');` then.

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".check-in").click(function () {
    $(this).closest(".separate").children(".secondary").fadeOut(200);
    $(this).closest(".separate").children(".main").find("object").css('visibility','visible');
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working just fine in my fiddle.

Did you style your object?

Did you make sure it's hidden initially?

```
$("object").hide();
```

I added [THE OBJECT] as it's content to see it.

```
<object class="checked">[THE OBJECT]</object>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/u6x84/